# how to bind jquery promise to an event

Tags: jquery, promise

I want to start my application only after all the  request is complete.How can i use jquery promise method to check if all the images in the request have been converted to bit 64 and then start the application. Thanks in advance for the help :)

```
function BuildImageUrl(src) {
        var dataURL;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = src;

        img.onerror = function(err) {
        console.log(err)
        };

         img.onload = function() {
         debugger;
         var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
         canvas.width = this.width;
         canvas.height = this.height;
         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
         dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
         return dataURL;
        };

    }

    OData.defaultHttpClient.enableJsonpCallback = false;
            OData.read("request url",
            function (data, request) {
              debugger;
              data.results.forEach(function(model,index){
                var path = "image path from response;
                var url = BuildImageUrl(path);
              }); 
            }
    );
```

Comment: You need `BuildImageUrl` to return a `promise` ("promise to return a url") using a `deferred` object created in that method. The deferred is `resolve`ed when the image load event triggers. Accumulate the promises and use `$.when` to listen for all of them to have completed.

Comment: Note: Currently you are attempting to `return dataURL` from inside an event callback. That value will not be returned from the call to `BuildImageUrl`. That value is simply returned to the `onload` event caller (and thrown away)

Comment: Thank you @TrueBlueAussie for the  help :) ,i am knew to javascript and jquery so i dont know how to write  deffered ,it would be gr8 help if you could throw some more light in to it

Comment: Added answer below. Hope it helps. Deferreds and promises take a bit of getting used too, but it is a great pattern.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Is there a way i can start the next request after getting the response of the first request .Becacause i have to insert it in db with an id .

Comment: I would need more information about the *broader aim* of this software to give proper advice. Queuing the requests with `.then` will slow it down a lot and there are workarounds for requiring server-ids.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Actually i have to save the response of each request into websql and map it with the id key in the corresponding model.The output of this comes as all the requests are send once and responses come randomly.so how can i map it with the id of the model

Comment: Sorry to say that makes little sense to me out of context. Can you show any of the server code in your question so I can work out what the IDs need to be connected to? (note: this seems to be mutating into a new question, so you may want to start a new question instead of adding to this one)

Answer (score 2):

**First part of the solution:**

You need `BuildImageUrl` to return a promise ("promise to return a url") using a deferred object created in that method. The deferred is resolved when the image load event triggers.

```
function BuildImageUrl(src) {
    var deferred = $.deferred();
    var dataURL;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;

    img.onerror = function (err) {
        // On error, reject the result (you may not want this as it will abort all subsequent deferreds)
        deferred.reject(err)
    };

    img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        // Resolve the deferred to return the result
        deferred.resolve(dataURL);
    };
    // return the promise to return a dataURL at a later time
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

**Second part - wait for all deferreds to complete using `$.when`:**

```
OData.defaultHttpClient.enableJsonpCallback = false;

// Array to hold all the promise
var my_array = [];
OData.read("request url", function (data, request) {
    debugger;
    data.results.forEach(function (model, index) {
        var path = "image path from response;
        // Add next promise to array
        my_array.push(BuildImageUrl(path));
    }); 
  });

 // Wait for all promises to complete (or any 1 to fail)
 $.when.apply($, my_array).done(function(){
     // Do something when they all complete
 }).fail(function(){
     // Do something else if any one of them fails (you probably do not want this)
 });
```

Comment: when am using this method the base64 thats generated is only half of the original image